# Download data from unread emails into separate files Python

Tags: python, email, csv, fetch, imaplib

I'm trying to download data from unread emails into csv files, in the sense, each unread email data goes into a separate csv file. I'm able to use imaplab and email to get the body of unread emails but I do not know how to save them into separate csv files and name them with the first line of the email body. Here's my code so far.

```
import imaplib
import email
server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
server.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
server.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')
resp, items = server.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
for mail in items[0].split():
    resp, data = server.fetch(mail, '(RFC822)')
    body = data[0][1]
    msg = email.message_from_string(body)
    content = msg.get_payload(decode=True)
    print content
```

Thank you.

SOLUTION:

```
import email, imaplib, os

detach_dir = '.'

# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login('email@gmail.com', 'password')
m.select("[Gmail]/All Mail") 

resp, items = m.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")
for mail in items[0].split():
    resp, data = m.fetch(mail, '(RFC822)')
    body = data[0][1]
    msg = email.message_from_string(body)
    content = msg.get_payload(decode=True)

    filename = content[2:7]
    counter = 1


    if not filename:
        filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, 'bin')
        counter += 1

    file_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)


    if not os.path.isfile(file_path) :

        fp = open(file_path+".csv", 'wb')
        fp.write(content)
        fp.close()
m.logout()
```

Comment: Once you have the data you want to save, use [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to create an object and write the data onto it. It's not harder than writing to a regular file.

Comment: @user3557327 Thank you for your response. I have more than 1000 outputs from a website and I'd like to download those into separate CSV files. I cannot run the program 1000 times.

Comment: Why do you think user3557327's suggestion requires that you run the program 1000 times?

Comment: @RossRidge I have no idea how to automate it. I'd really appreciate if you could help me with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
        for files in att_path:
            data = content.replace(" ", ",") #replaces if the delimiter is anything other than a ",". 
            fp = open(att_path+".csv", 'wb')
            fp.write(data)
            fp.close()
```

This would write the files properly delimited